# Customizing antd tree component style

Tags: html, css, antd

i am trying to add an info icon to each leave in an antd tree component. However if the leave title is too long it forces the suffixed info icon to appear out of the parent container.
This problem is depicted in the pictutr below.
Also here is a link to the a code snippet demonstrating the problem.
https://codesandbox.io/s/directory-antd4102-forked-46tqe?file=/index.css

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Do you want the suffixed icon to wrap into the next line if the leave title is too long? Or do you expect the green box to grow wider and keep the leave title and suffixed icon in a single long line?

Comment: i want the text to be truncated with triple dots went the width of the leaf grows wider than the parent container width. As you can see above when the text is too long the text is truncated later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep the explicit `300px` width on the parent container `.wrapper`. Then you could just give the `.ant-tree-title` elements (leave titles) a `max-width` property of around `200px` so they cannot grow larger than the remaining space in `.wrapper`. The value of `200px` leaves a bit of room for the suffixed icons that are aligned to the right side of each leaf.

This way each leave title and suffixed icon will maintain the ellipsis (...) for long titles while keeping the title and suffixed icon inside the `.wrapper` content box.

```css
.ant-tree-node-content-wrapper-normal .ant-tree-title {
    display: inline-flex !important;
    justify-content: flex-start !important;
    text-align: left !important;
    min-width: 0;
    max-width: 200px; /* Restrict leave titles so they don't overflow */
    border: 1px solid gray;
}

/* right align the suffixed icons */
.icon {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
```

[image: CodeSandbox antd tree component style]